# Macro for textinput without any formatting

Tags: math-mode, macros

Is there a LaTeX macro that just compiles whatever I type into it? Something like `\text` or `\textnormal`. I want to display a LaTeX code inline without any formatting, but don't want to escape everything. Especially I want to display the text in caption as well.

This is the LaTeX code I want to have as regular text.

```
x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are probably looking for `\verb`: `\verb!x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}!`

Comment: @egreg Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. So hard to google things sometimes, when you don't know how to word it.

Comment: The LateX keyword is "verbatim", and their are various macros and environments that provide this kind of text with different options, depending on your need.